# JS Regex Pattern Used In Data-XXX Attributes Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i am trying to set regex pattern in input field attribute and use js to validate it.. but somehow it's not working..

if i use same pattern directly on js it works.. but not through the attribute..

here is my html code:

```
<input type="text" name="tPhoneNumber" id="tPhoneNumber" style="width:90%;" data-name="Phone Number" data-group="NewEntry" data-required="y" data-pattern="/^\+44[\d]{10}$/" />
```

and here is the js code:

```
//this works
if (/^\+44[\d]{10}$/.test(inputs[i].value))
{
    console.log("matched");
}
else
{
    console.log("not matched");
}
//this does not works, it's always failed regardless whether the text box has correct value or not
if(!inputs[i].value.match(inputs[i].dataset.pattern))
{
    var msg = `Invalid data entered in "${inputs[i].dataset.name}" field!<br/>You have entered = ${inputs[i].value}`;
    return ShowError(msg);
}
```

what i am doing wrong here?

thanks in advance

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since data attribute inside your input is just string, not a `RegExp` object, you should remove slashes `/` at start and end of its value: `data-pattern="^\+44[\d]{10}$"`

```js
var input = document.getElementById('tPhoneNumber');
//this works
if (/^\+44[\d]{10}$/.test(input.value))
{
    console.log("matched");
}
else
{
    console.log("not matched");
}

//this should works too
if(!input.value.match(input.dataset.pattern))
{
    console.log(`Invalid data entered in "${input.dataset.name}" field!<br/>You have entered = ${input.value}`);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="tPhoneNumber" id="tPhoneNumber" value="+440123456" style="width:90%;" data-name="Phone Number" data-group="NewEntry" data-required="y" data-pattern="^\+44[\d]{10}$" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your in-code regex works because you are using a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#regexp_literals), which creates an instance of [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). A regular expression literal is a regular expression placed between forward-slashes (optionally followed by flags).

Your attribute pattern does not work because [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) are represented [as strings in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

So when you call `.match(dataset.pattern)`, you pass a string instead of a `RegExp` object. The string [converts to a `RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#a_non-regexp_as_the_parameter).

The leading and trailing forward-slashes are JS syntax for creating a `RegExp` object, so `data-pattern` and your JS `RegExp` are not the same.

`data-pattern` should only represent the regular expression, so that it will be converted correctly; **remove the forward-slashes** of `data-pattern`.

Comment: thanks a lot! i would also mark yours one as answer as well. but only can can be marked as so! however, i just upvote you. Thanks again.. for the explanation.. !